# Isomorphism between Hilbert spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I want to show that the function

$$ L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{O})\longrightarrow L^2(\widetilde{\Omega},\mathcal{O}) \colon f \longmapsto f|_{\widetilde{\Omega}}$$

is a isomorphism, where $L^2(\mathbb{C},\mathcal{O})$ is the hilbert space of square-integrable holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded domain and for $E\subset \Omega$ finite we define $\widetilde{\Omega}:=\Omega \setminus E$.

Comment: Note: $L^2(\mathbb{C},\mathcal{O}) = \{0\}$.

Comment: The point is to show that an isolated singularity of a (locally) square-integrable holomorphic function is necessarily removable.

Comment: If we have $E=\left\lbrace a_1,\dots,a_n \right\rbrace$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, why should those points be isolated singularities of $f$? Anyway, this would explain why the set $E$ has to be finite - because else we would have a limit point.

Comment: One can have infinite $E$, even allowing some limit points in $\Omega$, it just mustn't be too bad.

Comment: Ok, but we have that $E$ is finite.

Comment: I think I was able to prove the case $\Omega=B_r(0)$  and $\widetilde{\Omega}=B_r(0)\setminus\left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$. (By inspecting the Laurent series I found out that the coefficient $a_{-1}$ has to be $0$ so that $f\in L^2$.) But how can I argue if $\Omega$ is arbitrary and we have multiple poles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, the restriction $\rho \colon L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{O}) \to L^2(\widetilde{\Omega},\mathcal{O})$ is an isometry. So it remains to see that it is surjective, hence that for every $f\in L^2(\widetilde{\Omega},\mathcal{O})$, every point $a\in E$ is a removable singularity.

Since $E$ is finite, there is an $R > 0$ such that $D_{2R}(0) \subset \Omega$ and $\lvert a-b\rvert > R$ for all $b \in E\setminus\{a\}$. To simplify the notation, we may assume that $a = 0$.

For every $0 < r < R$, then consider the annulus $A_r = \{ z : r < \lvert z\rvert < R\}$ and the restriction $\rho_r \colon L^2(\widetilde{\Omega},\mathcal{O}) \to L^2(A_r,\mathcal{O})$. As a restriction, $\rho_r$ is norm-decreasing, i.e.

$$\lVert \rho_r(f)\rVert_{L^2(A_r)} \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{L^2(\widetilde{\Omega})}$$

for all $f\in L^2(\widetilde{\Omega},\mathcal{O})$. On the annulus $A_r \subset \widetilde{\Omega}$, every $f\in L^2(\widetilde{\Omega},\mathcal{O}) \subset \mathcal{O}(\widetilde{\Omega})$ has a Laurent expansion

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n.$$

By the choice of $R$, the Laurent series converges in a punctured disk $\{ 0 < \lvert z\rvert < R+\varepsilon\}$, hence it converges uniformly on $A_r$. (Note: locally uniform convergence would suffice, but uniform convergence simplifies a few steps.)

Now one needs to check that the monomials $(z^k)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ are mutually orthogonal in $L^2(A_r,\mathcal{O})$.

Then, we see that

$$\lVert \rho_r(f)\rVert_{L^2(A_r)} = \int_{A_r} \lvert f(z)\rvert^2 \,d\lambda = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \lvert c_n\rvert^2 \int_{A_r} \lvert z\rvert^{2n}\,d\lambda \leqslant \int_{\widetilde{\Omega}} \lvert f(z)\rvert^2\,d\lambda.$$

Letting $r \to 0$, the only way for the left hand side to remain finite is that $c_n = 0$ for all $n < 0$, which means that the singularity of $f$ in $0$ is removable.

That holds for every singularity $e\in E$, hence $\rho$ is surjective.